# use jquery validation plugin in mvc form page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to use jquery validation plugin on a mvc form page to check certain required fields. However, the error messages that i am getting are the validation rules of my view model. Does anyone happen to know why the rules that i set in jquery.validate is not displayed?

here is my view model

```
public class ViewModelA
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "invalid name")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }}
```

and here is my mvc web form (assumming jquery validation unobtrusive library is imported correctly)

```
@model ViewModelA
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id="AAA"})){
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientName, new { @class = "text-bold " })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientName, @class = "input-text required" })

}
```

in my jquery controller, i am trying to validate

```
    $("#AAA").validate({
      onsubmit: false,
      rules: {
        ClientName: {
          required: true
        },
      },
      messages: {
        ClientName: {
          required: 'validation message from jquery'
        },
      }
    });
```

but this message can't be displayed. i think i'm using jquery validation library correctly. But the viewmodel somehow reset my html or js which cause the FE validation not working. I have also tried deleting that @Html.ValidationMessageFor. Although the error messages from viewmodel is not showing, the FE error message does not show either

Comment: Just guessing, but the unobtrusive javascript validation may be processed after the `.validate` method and overriding your settings. Try setting `ClientValidationEnabled` and `key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" ` to `false` in your `web.config` files to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @user3397656 I have the same problem as yours, did you manage to solve it? 
If yes, please tell me how?

Comment: @Dark_Knight, sorry for the late response. There is an angular script that is also loaded on that page and i imported the plugin twice (in both angular script and mvc page). I solved the problem by deleting the reference on that angular script. Hope this helps!